# What rigid graphs can be decomposed into triangles such that each edge is in exactly one triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, eulerian-path, robotics

Is there a general algorithm/condition to tell if a graph can be decomposed into triangles such that each edge is in exactly one triangle (the graph $G$ has a set of subgraphs such that each subgraph is isomorphic to $K_3$, and each edge of G appears in exactly one of the triangles)?

Is it possible to enumerate the graphs that have an infinitesimally rigid embedding in $R^3$, and can also be decomposed into triangles up to a certain number of nodes?

Necessary conditions are that the number of edges in each graph must be divisible by 3, and the degree of each node must be even, but I don't think those conditions are sufficient.

One family of graphs that meets these conditions are the graphs formed by the edges of all n-gonal bipyramids where n is even.

For my PhD I built a robot composed of discrete triangles assembled into an octahedron shape.  I am curious what other robots I could make using a similar system. (see image)

[Robot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFu18.jpg)

Comment: (not see image...)

Comment: Fixed, thanks!  I'm too new to embed it, but I fixed the link, and also put it as my profile picture as well.

Comment: You say exactly one triangle, but in the picture you have the left edge on the floor in two triangles. Can you clarify please?

Comment: While each edge is a part of two triangles in the overall structure, the challenge is to break the graph $G$ into $K_3$ subgraphs such that each edge is part of exactly one of the $K_3$ subgraphs.  So the 8 triangle faces of the octahedral robot are divided up such that 4 physical triangles (the red triangles in the robot picture), define the whole structure.

Comment: Triangle decomposition is NP-complete for general graphs (The NP-Completeness of Some Edge-Partition Problems, Ian Holyer). I don't know about rigid graphs but that's probably still the case.

Comment: Great reference to know that this is NP-complete in the general case, which I suppose means there will be no general algorithm. I would still be interested in a technique to enumerate the possible graphs for a low number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you take any graph without triangles which has all vertices of degree 3 (a cubic graph) and form the line graph of that cubic graph, then the resulting graph will have all edges in exactly one of the triangles formed around where the cubic vertices were.

For instance; taking the pentagonal prism:
[image: pentagonal prism]

It has the following graph as its line graph, which can be seen to have every edge in one triangle:

[image: line graph with all edges in 1 triangle]

Although it is difficult in general to verify that a graph has this property (if it has a suitable number of vertices and edges), it is straightforward to create more simply by locating some vertices which are not already joined to all others and adding either a triangle between those vertices or adding a new vertex forming triangles with it and pairs of vertices from the original graph.

For instance, your hexagonal bipyramid can either be formed by adding a vertex of degree 6 as part of 3 triangles to a windmill, or a vertex of degree 4 to a 7-vertex graph or a triangle to an 8-vertex graph. All of the base graphs have vertices of degree 2 though, so it is probably best to generate all graphs and then do your rigidity check.

[image: Bipyramid formation]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed thought!  I see that taking the line graph of a graph where all vertices are of degree three produces a graph where each edge can be partitioned to exactly one triangle. The line graph of $K_4$ produced the octahedron shape used in the robot. I think this guarantees that each triangle connects with only one other triangle at each vertex.  But what about the case where each vertex may be a part of more than 2 triangles? For example, a hexagonal bipyramid?

Comment: @NathanUsevitch can you say a bit more about what you mean by rigid? Would that be equivalent to minimum degree 4 or edge-connectivity at least 3?

Comment: By rigid I mean that the graph has an infinitesimally rigid embedding, or that it is has no motions relative to itself without changing edges lengths.  Each node being connected to 3 edges is a necessary but not sufficient condition (and the triangle requirement that each node has even degree means that each node must be connected to a minimum of 4 edges in this case).  However, I don't think there is a general connectivity condition in 3D that ensures rigidity.